# GKE RollingUpdate having downtime

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to do a rolling update of a deployment and I am still getting about 2 seconds of downtime.   Did I misconfigure my yaml?   I am also using ambassador as the API gateway and not entirely sure whether the issue is in the API Gateway or in the deployment.

I wrote a simple shell script that runs a curl every second and I always have about 2 seconds of downtime with this config.  Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my relevant config.

deployment Method:

```
kubectl apply -f MY_DEPLOYMENT.yaml
```

Deployment Snippet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-service-rf
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-service-rf
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 4
      maxUnavailable: 0%
```

Liveness and Readiness Probe:

```
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /health/liveness
      port: 80
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 3
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /health/readiness
      port: 80
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    successThreshold: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you're YAML seems fine, I suspect the 2 second down time may be due to a TCP connection that did not flush properly to the pod that is being replaced.

Can you add a prestop hook to your container to make sure that all TCP connections are drained before terminating the pod?

Answer (score 0):

The `maxUnavailable` should be the number of pods that can be unavailable at the same time and not the percentage of these pods. My guess is that by putting the `%` sign on the value you cause a parsing error. Which results in this behavior.